# retrieve data from different columns of single table into a single view page in mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am doing a project and I got confused in a particular session that I have a table called deposits

```
public partial class Deposit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SavingBank { get; set; }
}
```

created a controller called Products and an ActionResult called Deposits

```
   public ActionResult Deposits()
    {
        var ShowResult = db.Deposits.ToList();
        return View(ShowResult);
    }
```

When I check the code using breakpoints a got all the values from the table but in the view page , I need to get the data of each item from table with different places in that single view page(eg- I need to get the data of savingBank from table at the top of the view page, FixedDeposit at the end of the view page etc, all the entries should be made on the single page),

```
@model List<Project.Models.Deposit>


 <div class="saving_cont">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="main_hed">Saving Bank Account</h3>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <img src="../assests/image/saving_bank.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            @Html.Raw(Model.SavingBank)
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
```

but when I run the code it shows a compilation error that " 'List' does not contain a definition for 'SavingBank' and no extension method 'SavingBank' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

why is this error coming?? Why can't I retrieve different columns of table into a single page ?? can  anyone please help me to solve my problem ??

Comment: it is a List< which means there are multiple items, you will need to iterate on it using for or for each loop to access each item

Comment: when I change my code and give the for loop but @html.raw is not working inside the loop, instead html.hiddenfor is working ??, but I need raw data to retrieve from table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model` is of the type `List<Deposit>`, not `Deposit`. `SavingBank` is a property of a single `Deposit`.

If you are targeting a single item in the list, you will have access to that property:

```
foreach(Deposit deposit in Model) 
{
    <div>
        @Html.Raw(deposit.SavingBank)
    </div>
}
```

You could also do something like `Model.First().SavingBank` if that's what you're after.

Comment: But when I give as u said, shows the error The type or namespace name 'Deposit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?), and how come this happens??

Comment: @user256: This is because you don't have a reference to the `Models` namespace. You'll need to spell out the fully qualified name `ThaniyamBank.Models.Deposit` instead of just `Deposit`, or add `<add namespace="ThaniyamBank.Models"/>` to `system.web\pages\namespaces` in web.config, if that is a namespace you'll frequently use in your views.

Comment: I got it , when I change foreach(Deposit deposit in Model) to foreach (var deposit in Model ).

Comment: ThankYou For your help :)